# ansible creating virtualenv with root owner

Tags: ansible, virtualenv

This Ansible task creates a virtualenv (good!), but the directory (/home/chris/.virtualenvs/foobar) is owned by root (not so good):

```
- name: install requirements
  pip:
    chdir: /home/chris/website
    requirements: ./requirements.txt
    virtualenv: /home/chris/.virtualenvs/foobar
```

But what's driving me nuts is that the next task fails, apparently because of the root ownership

```
- name: copy sitecustomize.py
  file:
    src: /home/chris/website/sitecustomize.py
    dest: /home/chris/.virtualenvs/foobar/lib/python2.7/sitecustomize.py
    remote_src: yes
```

I think the problem I really want to solve is creating the .virtualenv so that it's owned by "chris".  Any idea how to force that?

Failing that, how can get the "copy" task to run with the same permissions as the "pip" task, so that I can copy my file?

EDIT:  Solved second problem -- I needed to use the "copy" task, not the file task.  So this...

```
- name: copy sitecustomize.py
  copy:
    src: /home/chris/website/sitecustomize.py
    dest: /home/chris/.virtualenvs/foobar/lib/python2.7/sitecustomize.py
    remote_src: yes
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: There is no way Ansible would create a directory owned by root, if you used `chris` account to run it. Use account with minimal/appropriate privileges.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run `pip` as `chris`:

```
- name: install requirements
  pip:
    chdir: /home/chris/website
    requirements: ./requirements.txt
    virtualenv: /home/chris/.virtualenvs/foobar
  become: yes
  become_user: chris
```

And to be consistent, make `chris` the owner of `sitecustomize.py`:

```
- name: copy sitecustomize.py
  file:
    src: /home/chris/website/sitecustomize.py
    dest: /home/chris/.virtualenvs/foobar/lib/python2.7/sitecustomize.py
    remote_src: yes
    group: chris
    owner: chris
```

Comment: Unsupported parameters for (pip) module: become, become_user according to official doc